# CSS Image Hover with Rotation - Web Kit Issues / Works fine in Firefox

Tags: css, webkit, hover, rotation, css-transforms

*Links to examples removed*

Problem: Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari) are having an issue with the rotation class I created on the page.  If I remove the rotation class on the content div, the large images that appear on hover appear in the correct position.

Firefox has no issue with the rotated content div.  I am on a Mac so I cannot test IE.

Comment: Where(in which element) the large image appears? And how do you make it? by CSS or JS?

Comment: Sorry, I never received a notification through e-mail about messages in this question.  Glad you found it in the CSS, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given the `.thumbnail` class `position:relative` so it's creating it's own position context. The fixed position you've given `.thumbnail:hover span` will work with it's 0 top position as the top of the `.thumbnail` parent.

Just take away `position: relative` from `.thumbnail` and set the `top` position for `.thumbnail:hover span` to the value you want it placed (relative now, to the top of the window, because it has `position: fixed`.

Hope my explanation was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's enaugh to set only in `.thumbnail:hover span{visibility:visible}`
The rest code should be such

```
.thumbnail span { 
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    height:530px;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 460px; 
}
```

The position should be the same. In your code you wrote *absolute* but in hover mode set *fixed*. And if you want the image to appear in the same place you should position it relative to ***#portfolio*** but not ***.thumbnail***. So add these:

```
#portfolio {position:relative}
```

Remove

```
.thumbnail {position:relative}
```